# fogbugz: Is there a way to view the history of a case using the api

Tags: fogbugz

I want to get all the history of a case. Is this possible through the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the `search` command, supplying the bug ID as the query (`q` parameter) and asking for the `events` column in the results (with the `cols` parameter). The URL for this will look like:

```
http://server/api.asp?cmd=search&q=1000&cols=events&token=xxx
```

In the returned XML, the `<case>` element (there will be just one if the bug ID is valid) will have an `<events>` child element with `<event>` children containing the history; the XML format is documented in the [API documentation](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/API.html#xmloutput). If you just wanted to dump the comments on a case, for example, you could enumerate the results of the XPath query `/response/cases/case/events/event/s`.

Answer (score 1):

The folks at Fog Creek Software have started a fantastic "StackExchange" using, essentially, the same software as Stack Overflow. You might want to check it out.

[Fogbugz Knowledge Exchange](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Updating history, this is now replaced with their own help website.